# Unable to add values in existing JSON response in Hyperledger Composer Rest Api

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

**My Code for creating wallet using hyperledger composer REST API :**

```
async function walletCreation(tx) {
var userId = {
userId: tx.userId,
};
var walletPassword = {
walletPassword: tx.walletPassword,
};

const encryptWalletId = await request.post({ uri: 
'http://payment.api.in/encrypt', json: userId });
const encryptWalletPassword = await request.post({ uri: 
'http://payment.api.in/encryptPass', json: walletPassword });
 return getAssetRegistry('com.payment.UserWallet')
.then(function (userAssetRegistry) {
  // Get the factory for creating new asset instances.
var factory = getFactory();
  // Create the wallet.
tx.walletId = encryptWalletId.walletId;
var walletAsset = factory.newResource('com.payment', 'UserWallet', 
tx.walletId);
walletAsset.userId = tx.userId;
walletAsset.walletPassword = encryptWalletPassword.walletPassword;
walletAsset.currency = tx.currency;
walletAsset.walletBalance = 0;
walletAsset.createdDate = new Date();
userAssetRegistry.add(walletAsset);


})
.catch(function (error) {

throw new Error("wallet creation failed");

});

}
```

**Below is the request body(Swagger input) for wallet creation
:**

```
{
  "$class": "com.payment.WalletCreation",
  "userId": "Hari",
  "walletPassword": "hari@123",
  "currency": "INR",
  "walletBalance": 0
}
```

**Below is the expected response for above input:**

```
 {
   "$class": "com.payment.WalletCreation",
   "userId": "Hari",
   "status":"Wallet creation successfully",
   "WalletId":"1234567asder",
   "walletId": 0,
   "walletPassword": "hari@123",
   "currency": "INR",
   "walletBalance": 0,
   "transactionId": 
   "deee486e2e74647635e53e316f2a8e1b71ab500e9dd3bf15945665a4025fc208"
  }
```

**But this is what am getting as response**

```
  {
  "$class": "com.payment.WalletCreation",
  "userId": "Hari",
  "walletPassword": "hari@123",
  "currency": "INR",
  "walletBalance": 0,
  "transactionId": 
  "deee486e2e74647635e53e316f2a8e1b71ab500e9dd3bf15945665a4025fc208"
 }
```

Kindly help me to fix this, stuck for 2 days unable to fix the bug

Comment: hi there, not enough detail or context. If you want to return JSON from a transaction function - see https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/js_scripts#returning-data-from-transaction-processor-functions

Answer (score 0):

1. There's an example in https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/call-out (3rd code block) of exactly what you're trying to do eg (replace with below)

   FYI you can't re-assign `tx.walletId` (its part of the transaction input!). Also new Date() is non deterministic.
2. The response is entirely what you would expect of the TRANSACTION post - you need to check your ASSET instance (you're creating) in the registry 'com.payment.UserWallet' using /GET, for the asset you're adding. Besides, your expected response wouldn't match your function.

Answer (score 0):

Returning a complex type from a transaction processor function

Link: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/js_scripts#returning-data-from-transaction-processor-functions

Model file:

```
    namespace org.sample

    concept MyConcept {
        o String value
    }

    @returns(MyConcept)
    transaction MyTransaction {

    }
```

Transaction processor function:

```
    /**
     * Handle a transaction that returns a concept.
     * @param {org.sample.MyTransaction} transaction The transaction.
     * @returns {org.sample.MyConcept} The concept.
     * @transaction
     */
    async function myTransaction(transaction) {
        const factory = getFactory();
        const concept = factory.newConcept('org.sample', 'MyConcept');
        concept.value = 'hello world!';
        return concept;
    }
```

[Profile ZB](http://www.zeimbeekor.pro) @zeimbeekor

Bye!